# converting linq .Any in subquery to sql

Tags: linq

I'm trying to learn linq..I have the following linq query..

var abc = consumers.Where(w => plays.Any(x => x.consumerid == w.consumerid));

I would appreciate if someone could help me with its corresponding sql query.

consumers have just two fields.. consumerid and period both string.
plays also have two fields.. consumerid and playid both string.

Based on answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25283515/converting-linq-expression-to-sql-server-query).. I tried abc.ToString() but that did not help..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplified query:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    consumers x 
WHERE    EXISTS
        (
        SELECT  *
        FROM    plays w
        WHERE   x.consumerid = w.consumerid
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select * from consumers c left join palys p on c.consumerid = p.consumerid
```